# Solve the complex number equation $|z|+z=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Solve the equation $|z|+z=1$.

This is my thought process so far:

$$|z|=1-z$$

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1-z$$

$$a^2+b^2=1-2z+z^2$$

$$a^2+b^2=1-2(a+bi)+(a+bi)^2$$
$$a^2+b^2=1-2a-2bi+a^2+2abi-b^2$$
$$a^2+2b^2=1-2a-2bi+a^2+2abi$$
$$2b^2=1-2a-2bi+2abi$$

Not sure what quite to do after this stage. Perhaps I am approaching this question wrongly.

**Edit: the book I'm picking this question up from clearly states "Solve for $z\in\mathbb{c}$", so perhaps is there another solution with an imaginary part as well?**

Comment: Try to visualize $z$ and $|z|$ as vectors in the complex plane. What determines the imaginary part of $z+|z|$?

Comment: $|z|$ is real, and $1$ is real, so....

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 } + a + ib = 1$ comparing real imaginary parts $\implies a = \frac 12$ and $b = 0$ ?

Comment: $z=1-|z|$, so $z$ is a real number. If $z<0$ then $z=1+z$, a contradiction. So $z\ge 0$, $z=1-z$, $z=1/2$.

Comment: Missing square in the second line.

Comment: @YvesDaoust corrected, thanks for spotting the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a+ib=1$$ immediately implies $b=0$ by identification of the imaginary part(s).

You preferred a harder way, with squaring,

$$a^2+b^2=1-2a-2ib+a^2-b^2+2iab$$ and again by identification

$$-2b+2ab=0$$

yields $b=0$ or $a=1$.

Now plugging $a=1$,
$$1+b^2=-b^2$$ is a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to write it as $\,z = 1 - |z|\,$, then compare the magnitudes on the two sides where the RHS is a real number, so  $\,\require{cancel} \bcancel{|z|^2} = \left(1 - |z|\right)^2 = 1 - 2 |z| + \bcancel{|z|^2} \iff |z| = \frac{1}{2}\,$.

Substituting back into the original equation gives $\,z = 1 - |z| = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ More generally, the same approach can be used to solve $|z|+z=\alpha$ for arbitrary $\alpha \in \mathbb C$.

- Isolate $z$ to one side: $\;z = \alpha - |z|\,$.
- Conjugate: $\;\bar z = \overline\alpha - |z|\,$.
- Multiply the two: $\;\bcancel{|z|^2} = \big(\alpha - |z|\big)\big(\overline\alpha-|z|\big)=|\alpha|^2 + \bcancel{|z|^2} - 2 |z| \text{Re}(\alpha)\,$. 
  If $\,\text{Re}(\alpha) = 0\,$ no solutions exist unless $\,\alpha = 0\,$, and in that case the solution set is $\,z \in \mathbb R^{\le 0}\,$.
- Otherwise, solve for $|z|$: $\;|z| = \frac{|\alpha|^2}{2 \text{Re}(\alpha)}\,$. 
  If $\,\text{Re}(\alpha) \lt 0\,$ no solutions exist, since it would imply $\,|z| \lt 0\,$.
- Otherwise, substitute back into the original equation: $\;z = \alpha-|z|=\alpha-\frac{|\alpha|^2}{2 \text{Re}(\alpha)}\,$.

OP's problem is the case $\,\alpha=1\,$, so $\,z = 1 - \frac{|1|^2}{2 \cdot 1}=\frac{1}{2}\,$.

Answer (score 0):

The trigonometric (polar) form $ \ z \ = \ \rho·( \ \cos \theta \ + \ i·\sin \theta \ ) \ $ is also helpful.  The equation becomes
$$ |z| \ + \ z \ \ = \ \ \rho \ + \ \rho·( \ \cos \theta \ + \ i·\sin \theta \ ) \ \ = \ \ \rho·( \ \cos \theta \ + \ 1 \ ) \ + \ \rho  ·  \sin \theta · i \ \ = \ \ 1 \ + \ 0·i \ \ . $$

Plainly $ \ z \ = \ 0 \ $ is not a solution to the equation, so we can take $ \ \rho \ \neq \ 0 \ \ . \ $ "Matching" the imaginary parts gives us $ \ \rho   ·  \sin \theta \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ \theta \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ \pi \ \ . \ $  So $ \ z \ $ is a real number.  Equating the real parts then produces either
$$ \rho·( \ \cos 0 \ + \ 1 \ ) \ \ = \ \ 2·\rho \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ \ \text{or}  \ \ \ \rho·( \ \cos \pi \ + \ 1 \ ) \ \ = \ \  \rho·0 \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ . $$

The latter equation has no solution for $ \ \rho \ \ , \ $ so we conclude from the first equation that $ \ \rho \ = \ \frac12 \ \ , \ \ \theta \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ z \ = \ \frac12 \ \ $ is the only root of the equation.