# Solve the complex number equation $|z|-\bar{z}=i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, solution-verification

Solve the complex number equation $|z|-\bar{z}=i$.

The following was my thought process:

$$|z|=i+\bar{z}$$
Given that $Im(|z|)=0$, $Im(\bar{z})=-i$. Hence, $\bar{z}=a-i$ and $z=a+i$.

$$|z|=i+(a-i)$$

$$|z|=a$$

But since $z=a+i$, $|z|=\sqrt{a^2+1}$ and hence I've reached a contradiction, as $\sqrt{a^2+1}\neq a$.

Hence, there is no solution for $|z|-\bar{z}=i$, for $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What made you think that there was something wrong with what you did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You havent gone wrong anywhere. The contradiction tells that there does not exist any $z\in \mathbb{C}$  satisfying your condition.

Answer (score 3):

The posted solution is correct. Another way is to write it as $\,\bar z = |z| - i\,$, then take the conjugates on both sides $\,z = |z| + i\,$ and multiply the two to get $\,|z|^2=|z|^2 + 1\,$, so no solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a good one and your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a+ib=i$$ implies $b=1$, so $\sqrt{a^2+1}=a$ by identification.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with yours. Had an idea for an alternative.

$|z|=i+\bar{z}$

$|z|=-i+z$ by cojugating both sides.

$|z|=(z+\bar{z})/2$ by addition and halfing both sides.

The modulus is therefore equal to the real part, so the imaginary part must be zero. This means z is itself real.

Let $z=x$, $x$ is real.

Returning to the first expression, this implies

$x=i+x\implies i=0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Note: I used $z^\star$ because I could not do the conjugate bar on my drawing*

Here is a visual proof:

$|z|$ and $\bar z$ belong to the same black circle because $|z|=|\bar z|=\Big\lvert|z|\Big\lvert$, therefore $|z|-\bar z$ belongs to the blue circle which never crosses the $Y-$axis except in $0$.

In particular it cannot pass through $i$.

Comment: Arf, realizing I should have oriented $z^\star$ in the opposite direction... But this doesn't change the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's solve a more general problem. Suppose $\text{z}_1\space\text{z}_2\in\mathbb{C}$, solve:

$$\left|\text{z}_1\right|-\overline{\text{z}_1}=\text{z}_2\tag1$$

Let's assume $\text{z}_1=\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)i$ and $\text{z}_2=\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)i$, so we get:

$$\left|\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)i\right|-\overline{\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)i}=\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)i\tag2$$

Rewriting gives:

$$\sqrt{\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)^2+\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)^2}-\left(\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)i\right)=\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)i\tag3$$

So, we can write a system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)^2+\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)^2}-\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)=\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)\\
\\
\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)=\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Solving for $\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)$, gives:

$$\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)=\frac{\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)^2-\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)^2}{2\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)}\tag5$$

> Now, for your case it is not hard to see that we have a problem when $\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)\to0$ for $(5)$.

Answer (score 0):

As for your [earlier problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370644/solve-the-complex-number-equation-zz-1), the polar form $ \ z \ = \ \rho·( \ \cos \theta \ + \ i·\sin \theta \ ) \ $ is useful and here establishes the contradiction rather quickly.  This equation becomes

$$   |z| \ - \ \bar{z} \ \ = \ \ \rho \ - \ \rho·( \ \cos \theta \ - \ i·\sin \theta \ ) \ \ = \ \  \rho·( \ 1 \ - \  \cos \theta \ ) \ + \ \rho·\sin \theta·i  \ \ = \ \ 0 \ + \ 1·i \ \ . $$

As $ \ z \ = \ 0 \ $ clearly is not a solution of the equation, $ \ \rho \ \neq \ 0 \ \ . \ $  Equating the real parts of the equation produces $ \ \rho·( \ 1 \ - \  \cos \theta \ ) \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ which "forces" $ \ \cos \theta \ = \ 1 \ \Rightarrow \ \theta \ = \ 0 \ \ .^{*} \ $  But an attempt to "match" the imaginary parts leads us to $ \ \rho·\sin 0 \ = \ \rho·0 \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ $ which has no solution.  Hence, there is no $ \ z \ \in \ \mathbb{C} \ $ which is a root of this equation.

$ ^{*} $ An alternative interpretation is that $ \ \theta \ = \ 0 \ $ implies that $ \ z \ $ is a real number, but then the difference of two real numbers $ \ |z| - z \ $ cannot produce the imaginary $ \ i \ \ . $